# Automatic log out after period of inactivity with Identity Server and OpenId Connect

Tags: angular, logout, openid-connect, identityserver3, implicit-flow

I currently have an **angular 2 SPA** calling a **Web API**. I am using a Security Token Service implemented with **Identity Server 3** and the oidc-client-js javascript library to provide authentication and authorization to use the Web API.

The protocol is **OpenId Connect** using the **implicit flow**.

I have implemented **silent token refresh** based on this [artice](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Silent-Refresh-Refreshing-Access-Tokens-when-using-the-Implicit-Flow). This is in order to always have a current Access_Token when calling the API.

In order to log the user out after a period of inactivity I am using a javascript timer to call the **UserManager.signoutRedirect** method from the Oidc_Client_Js library.

This works, however I am concerned that this could be open to manipulation as the user's session is controlled by Javascript on the client.

My question is, are there any recommended techniques to apply a 'rolling' automatic sign-out on Single Page Apps secured with OpenId Connect?